# Jump links to another page and return back to the first page anchors successfully

Tags: menus

I have made a one page website with their jump links using id attribute (#). These jump links are provided in the navigation bar (header navigation menu).

Now, we want to add another page, but the problem is that when we are on this new page, the anchors (jump links) of the first page don't work. The only solution is to click the home URL to return to the first page of the website.Is there any other solution?

Comment: add a slash before the # in the navigation links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this http://wwww.yoursite.com/#anchor from another page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. I'm using the zerif lite(free) theme and my site URL is softaxe.com. In menus>display locations it is showing me this "Your theme supports one menu. Select which menu you would like to use." Kindly guide me if I can still use what you said.

Comment: Yes, you can use it, You need to add link as custom link

Comment: yes this completely works deepti I just need to make the new menu displayed on the new page with the anchors in the format you told me. Can we do this according to the problem discussed above. Thanks a lot for the great help you have provided me with.

Comment: Yes, You can do this. you need to add Menu. This tutorial may help you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TkXaoMIzQ4

Comment: adding the slash worked for me thank you very much for your help. Stack overflow is great and you are great!

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the navigation links – add a slash before the # in the navigation links like this: '/#jump1' instead of just '#jump1'

You will however have to use "Custom Links" instead of "Pages" to do this – see screenshot below:

[image]

…should do the trick…

Comment: adding the slash worked for me thank you very much for your help. Stack overflow is great and you are great!

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! :) Please feel free to mark the answer as the correct answer and/or up-vote if you think the answer was helpful…