# Jump to section on another page from menu item

Tags: menus

I have seen this thread [Jump links to another page and return back to the first page anchors successfully](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257789/jump-links-to-another-page-and-return-back-to-the-first-page-anchors-successfull) and I have this problem too.

The menu links work fine if called from the page with the sections on it. However, from another page clicking the menu link takes me to the section above the section I want to go to.

I added /#schedule for instance in the custom menu item. When you hover over the menu the browser shows that it will go to mysite.com/#schedule BUT that is not where it goes.

Comment: You may have to hard-code the full URL - not just /#schedule but http://example.com/#schedule. What's happening is that on some pages you are in a different directory, and if you're a couple of levels down, say on example.com/page1/page2, then the slash is actually taking you to example.com/page1#schedule which is the problem.

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine but I am afraid that I have tried that without success. I am going to the correct page but one section (div) above where I should be, but when called from the same page using the same link it goes to the correct section.